# How to put a number from string to foreach

Tags: php

Example of my string `$number = '1,10,40';`

How do I put the numbers into my foreach loop something like this.

```
foreach($array[$number[1]] as $one)
{
  foreach($array[$number[10]] as $two)
  {
     foreach($array[$number[40]] as $three)
     {
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense to me. What do you really want to achieve? Do you want an array with the numbers as key of the array? If so what should the value be?

Comment: is that $number variable the end result or do you start with that? not really clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Probably not what you want, but closest thing that I could think of: `$parts = explode(',', $number);` - gives you an array with 1, 10 and 40

Comment: Thanks @VladPreda I got it `explode`. You can move your comment to answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will something like:

```
function recursive($input) {
    if(is_string($input) {
         return recursive(explode(',', $input);
    }
    if(is_array($input) && !empty($input)) {
        $to = array_shift($input);
        for($i=0;$i<=$to;$i++) {
            recursive($input);
        }
    }
    if(empty($input) {
        //do here whatever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had a hard time understanding your question but this is what I can infer from what you've asked.  I hope it answers your question.

I think that what you are looking for here is the second for each loop in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
someexpression
```

where $key = 1 when $value = 1
and   $key = 2 when $value = 10
and   $key = 3 when $value = 40